# How to pass the id from a view to a controller to be used as the foreign key in another table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

As the title how to pass id to controller  to get related data to that id.

for example 
[image]

```
@foreach($persion_data as $person)

  {{$person['id']}}

                    @endforeach
```

### I want to send the id above  to the controller to get data from another table!

to make it even clearer

in procedural programming I will do it like this

```
while($persion = sqlsrv_fetch_array($persion_data ,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 


$id = $persion ['id'];
$customer = "SELECT * FROM [ccl].[customer] WHERE id = '$id' ";

$get_customer_info = sqlsrv_query($conn, $customer);
$get_customer_id = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_customer_info,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As you see I passed the id to query to get data from another table has relation with the id

how can I do this in laravel ??

I tried to use route but it has to be in url and someone has click it

and it won't work as the example above

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a relationship between the 2 models and in your view do

```
{{ $person->card->name }} //will display 'name' from the card
```

If the person has many cards, you create a one to many relationship in the person model.

```
public function cards() {
    return $this->hasMany(Card::class, 'person_id');
}
```

and in your view, you loop through the person and the person's cards

```
@foreach($person_data as $person)
    @foreach($person->cards as $card)
        {{ $card->name }} 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I though of this way, but  the page I want to create has many queries and some of them has post as foreign key and other by customer, I would do your way if I have one  foreign key  in all the tables i want to use!

Comment: If you really, really, really want to call functions from your views, then it's not controllers you need, but helpers. You make a helper with a function like `findUserCard($id)`. Which will then return the cards belonging to the users.

Comment: I will look for helper function, I know nothing about them in laravel. Also I can use relation between the tables, but the issue if one table has no data associated with same id as others  it  won't return any data.

Comment: I learn how to use  helper functions, but how to use them ?? I mean should I make the query inside the function ?  because I want to pass the value nothing more